# Task.Factory.StartNew doesn't always start the task

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

I'm seeing this strange behavior where the runtime sometimes doesn't start a task `Task.Factory.StartNew` when called. I am specifically going over it in the debugger, but for some reason the task does not run. This happens sporadically, sometimes the task starts and sometimes it doesn't.

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                        {
                            Extract(fileName);
                        }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);  

        private static void Extract(String fileName)
        {
   Trace.WriteLine("Extract------------------     ---------------      ---");
        }
```

Comment: How do you determine that it doesn't run (because it does!)?

Comment: I dont see Trace.WriteLine getting printed in the output window

Comment: When do you expect it to be printed? This is only guaranteed after the task has exited.

Comment: The task doesn't run at all. The OP has a simplified example, the real thread itself does a lot of things

Comment: How many tasks are you starting concurrently? StartNew queues the task for execution, so if you do StartNew on a bunch of tasks, some of the tasks may not run immediately.

Comment: Pick one from: running the release build, having your program terminate before the task finishes, swallowing exceptions, not waiting for the task and missing an AggregateException.  You'll need to do more work in your question to narrow that down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that the task code *is* running, but you're not seeing the output because it's not (always) being flushed to your screen/file/whatever.

Try calling [Trace.Flush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace.flush.aspx) after your WriteLine.

Comment: No, the OP has a simplified example, the real thread itself does a lot of things.

Comment: My guess, then, is that something is wrong with one of those other things

Comment: I have traced it to Trace.WriteLine not being written to VS output window. No idea how that can be...

Comment: @user1615362 Try to add `Thread.Sleep(very-large-number-here)` inside a `Task` and put a breakpoint there. You will see that `Task` indeed is running

Answer (score 1):

I've just faced a similar issue, although it did take me a couple weeks to burrow through the code to single it out. So the Task.StartNew makes use of the ThreadPool, if there aren't any available your task will be queued, hence the delay and the reason I wasn't able to find this error through an isolation test, as I always had enough threads in the pool. o.O MultiThreading fun :) 
You would solve this by creating and managing your own threadpool like class.